# memory issues updating attributes with woocommerce rest api

Tags: python, woocommerce-rest-api

a have a datastructure to update attributes of my woocommerce products

```
  {'update': [{'id': 14787,
       'attributes': [{'id': 1,
         'name': 'kleur',
         'position': 0,
         'variation': False,
         'visible': True,
         'options': 'zwart'},
        {'id': 6,
         'name': 'maat',
         'position': 1,
         'variation': True,
         'visible': True,
         'options': ['38', '40', '42', '44', '46', '48']}]},
      {'id': 14786,
       'attributes': [{'id': 1,
         'name': 'kleur',
         'position': 0,
         'variation': False,
         'visible': True,
         'options': 'zwart'},
        {'id': 6,
         'name': 'maat',
         'position': 1,
         'variation': True,
         'visible': True,
         'options': ['38', '40', '42', '44', '46']}]},
      {'id': 14785,
       'attributes': [{'id': 1,
         'name': 'kleur',
         'position': 0,
         'variation': False,
         'visible': True,
         'options': 'zwart'},
        {'id': 6,
         'name': 'maat',
         'position': 1,
         'variation': True,
         'visible': True,
         'options': ['40', '42', '44', '46', '48', '50']}]},
      {'id': 14784,
       'attributes': [{'id': 1,
         'name': 'kleur',
         'position': 0,
         'variation': False,
         'visible': True,
         'options': 'zwart'},
        {'id': 2,
         'name': 'cupmaat',
         'position': 1,
         'variation': True,
         'visible': True,
         'options': ['C75',
          'C80',
          'C85',
          'C90',
          'C95',
          'D70',
          'D75',
          'D80',
          'D85',
          'D90',
          'D95',
          'E65',
          'E70',
          'E75',
          'E80',
          'E85',
          'E90',
          'F65',
          'F70',
          'F75',
          'F80',
          'F85',
          'F90',
          'G70',
          'G75',
          'G80']}]},
          ...........'F85']}]}]}
```

update call:

```
from woocommerce import API

wcapi = API(
  url="https://www.mydomain.nl",
  consumer_key="key",
  consumer_secret="secret",
  timeout=500
)
response = wcapi.post("products/batch", data).json()
response
```

I get memory issues. There are 300 sku's in my list

Server log gives:

AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2097152 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.nl/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4247'

What is the best way to solve.

Comment: "There are 300 sku's in my list"
Could you just do it one at a time?

Comment: one sku is no problem

Comment: multiple sku's is also OK. I tested with 4. But 305 sku's give memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

I raised memory limit in PHP-settings of server to 256M.

Issue solved